# How to check if a device is connected to the system or not?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to invoke a function only if the device is connected to the system. So my problem is how can I check whether the device is connected or not through USB before invoking the function. Can anyone help...thanks in advance.

Comment: What system is it you're talking about?

Comment: Perhaps this answer on a similar question might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4748481/880511

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if Windows Phone 7 is connected to desktop Zune software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744399/detect-if-windows-phone-7-is-connected-to-desktop-zune-software)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to find out by using the NetworkInterfaceInfo class:

```
var typ = NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;
if(typ == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet){
    // do stuff
}
```

*Note: If you disconnect your computer from the internet, I think this is no longer valid.. But as long as you're connected to a computer that is connected to a network and Zune is running, this should work (not tested)*

Comment: Hey i am not checking the network connection,i just want to check whether the phone is connected to my desktop or laptop through USB.

Comment: This would require an established socket connection to an endpoint to work.

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen, my comment is still valid

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen
Hi, 

Thanks for your reply I guess it is working but I am still stuck at one thing 'var typ' is always set to 'NONE' whether I am connected to LAN cable or wireless internet or not connected to any internet at all(it should be 'Ethernet' if zune is connected in this case, correct me if I am wrong).

Thanks in Advance.